# Dynamically set useState for multiple sub menus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm working on creating a multi level menu and I have sucessfully created a toggle which opens the sub menu on click. The issue I am having however is on click, all of the sub menus are opening. Here is my code so far:

Function

```
const [isSubOpen, setIsSubOpen] = useState(false)

const toggleSubMenu = (index, e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(index.key)
    let test = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.id
    console.log(test)

    if (test == index.key) {
        setIsSubOpen(!isSubOpen)
    }
}
```

Menu

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href={item.url}
           onClick={toggleSubMenu.bind(this, { key })}
        >
        </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Sub menu

```
<div id={key} css={isSubOpen ? tw`block` : tw`hidden`}></div>
```

Comment: Where do you get your `key` from ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it into the example, I have amended the code

Comment: It will be easier for us if you are able to provide a `minimal reproducible` sample

Comment: I think you're using one state for all submenus, Right?
`<div id={key} css={isSubOpen ? tw`block` : tw`hidden`}></div>`

Comment: Yes I'm only using one state, but I would like this to only trigger on the relevant sub menu

Comment: Then create a separate component to use for list items where you can manage the state of each one independently.

Answer (score 1):

Using a single boolean for all of them will cause them all to open and close whenever the state changes. If you want to keep it all in one state, you can use an array or an object to manage each sub-menu. An array would be easiest, so I'll show an example of how that would work.

Your state would be an array consisting of booleans. Each index would represent a sub-menu, `false` would be closed and `true` would be open. So if you click to open the first sub-menu at index 0, you would set the array to `[true, false]`.

```js
// Initialize the state with `false` for each sub-menu
const [subMenuState, setSubMenuState] = useState([false, false])

const toggleSubMenu = (e, i) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    // Clone the array
    const newState = subMenuState.slice(0)

    // Toggle the state of the clicked sub-menu
    newState[i] = !newState[i]

    // Set the new state
    setSubMenuState(newState)
}
```

Whenever you call `toggleSubMenu`, you would pass the index as the second parameter like so:

```jsx
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onClick={e => toggleSubMenu(e, 0)}>
            Link 1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onClick={e => toggleSubMenu(e, 1)}>
            Link 2
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then reference that index in the sub-menu to see whether or not it's open:

```jsx
<div css={subMenuState[0] ? tw`block` : tw`hidden`}>Sub-menu 1</div>
<div css={subMenuState[1] ? tw`block` : tw`hidden`}>Sub-menu 2</div>
```

I'm not sure what the use case is here, but with most menus you want to close the other active sub-menus. For example, if sub-menu 1 is open and you click to open sub-menu 2, you want sub-menu 1 to close and sub-menu 2 to open. Here's how you would achieve that effect:

```js
const [subMenuState, setSubMenuState] = useState([false, false])

const toggleSubMenu = (e, i) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    // Clone the array
    const clone = subMenuState.slice(0)

    // Reset all sub-menus except for the one that clicked
    const newState = clone.map((val, index) => {
        if(index === i) {
            return val
        }
        return false
    })

    newState[i] = !newState[i]

    setSubMenuState(newState)
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Hope this was helpful!